# Why this is an empty object when module.exports is assigned an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I am trying to understand a simple concept regarding `this` keyword in Node.js. My question is the following:

I know that `this` keyword in Node.js refers to the scope of the module, not the global namespace. And when the module is defined through `module.exports`, the value of `this` should change. However, depending on what I assign to `module.exports`, the outcome is different, and this is what I do not understand. Please look at the following blocks of code:

1 - In first example, `module.exports.nameOfModule` is assigned a string. And `this` refers to an object containing this string:

```
module.exports.nameOfModule = 'This Tutorial Module';

console.log(this);
// > { nameOfModule: 'This Tutorial Module' }
```

2 - In second example, the `module.exports` is assigned an object. And `this` does refer to an empty object.

```
module.exports = {
  nameOfTheModule: 'This tutorial module.',
};

console.log(this);
// > {}
```

Why does this happen? Why I do not see my assigned object referred in `this` keyword in second example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this` does not change in a given context. In your second example, `this` still refers to the original object.

Comment: @Pointy are you talking about [`this`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut)

Comment: No I mean the `this` symbol. Once a value is bound to `this` in some scope of execution (like a module or a called function), it does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The exports variable is available within a module's file-level scope, and is assigned the value of module.exports before the module is evaluated.

> It allows a shortcut, so that module.exports.f = ... can be written
>   more succinctly as exports.f = .... However, be aware that like any
>   variable, if a new value is assigned to exports, it is no longer bound
>   to module.exports:  [`node ref`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut)

when you add a key on `module.exports` it doesn't overwrite it

[image]

But when you assign a complete new value `module.exports = 'some value'` it not bound to be `module.exports` it overshadows `exports` with new value,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Originally, both the `this` keyword and `module.exports` (and also the `exports` variable) refer to the same object. You can alter that object by adding a property to it, regardless how you refer to the object.

If you assign a new object to `module.exports`, then just that `.exports` property does not refer to the new object, while `this` still refers to the original object. It's not a magical getter that always refers to the same things as `module.exports`.